# Is there any gdb client implementation in python?

Tags: python, gdb

I have a gdb server running for an embedded target and I can connect to it with the gdb command line CLI. I would like to automate the client part.
Instead of automating the CLI (not very pretty, and I'm running on Windows), is there a python GDB client implementation that would allow me to send commands to the server?

Answer (score 1):

See https://bitbucket.org/minami/python-gdb-mi

Another approach is to just run your Python code directly in gdb.  gdb has had built-in Python scripting for a number of years now.

Comment: Right, but the problem is I want it the other way around: I want to interact with GDB from my application

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I'm on Windows. The link uses Linux specific libraries, but I'm trying to use it as a reference. It seems indeed the MI gdb interface is the most suitable approach for controlling gdb from a script